# php: command not found Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: php, xcode, compiler-errors, macos-monterey

I updated to Monterey and I am trying to build my xcode project.

I have a custom php script that runs in Build Phases and I am getting the following error.

```
/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftApp-aboxvgocemtxyjcdbgadfktiyxvd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftApp.build/Debug Dev-iphoneos/SiteSelectedLibraryApp.build/Script-025223DA20C597E100D80A6A.sh: line 3: php: command not found
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have installed php with brew install php@8.0. I can run php in the terminal now but xcode can't seem to find it.

Comment: I'm not a mac user nor do I use xcode, but it looks like xcode or your build tool cannot find the php binary. This could be due to it not being added to your path or the binary location changing after you ran brew install and your build tool expects PHP to be somewhere it is not.

Comment: Yeah Monterey removed the system version of php because it was deprecated. I think I just need to figure out where in xcode to tell it where to find it.

Comment: I don't know if mac has the terminal command `which` but I would run `which php` then check your $PATH system variable PHP isn't there or doesn't match the result of which, or where the binary is, i would update it.

Comment: @plato522, I have resolved this issue on my system (macOS Monterey) using the following steps mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.

After a lot of searching over the internet, I found this solution.

It would help if you went to this library: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

Follow these steps:

- On macOS, install Xcode Command Line Utilities:

```
xcode-select --install
```

- Install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- Fetch the formulae in this tap:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

- Install PHP 8.0

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

- After installing you have to link it:

```
brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

If this command throws an error, then select any one path it shows on the terminal and execute it:
For me, I selected this path to override:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

- Restart the terminal and test your PHP version:

```
php -v
```

- Now check with this command, does it gives you the waring of `already linked`:

```
brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

[image]

That's it.

Now Xcode will run the PHP script without any error.